# Consolidate data from multiple specified files into 1 Master Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have adapted a code I found a while back that allows me to select files from the File Dialog, and consolidates the data into a single Master sheet. The code works as it is, but I need help changing the functionality a bit.

Instead of having to manually select the files, I would like the macro to automatically select 5 files that will always have the same File Name and File Path.

I think the part of the code that needs updating is the `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)` section.

```
Dim CurrentBook As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import")
Dim IndvFiles As FileDialog
Dim FileIdx As Long
Dim i As Integer, x As Integer

ChDrive "P:\"

'----Opens File Dialog window--------
Set IndvFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With IndvFiles
.InitialFileName = "FILE PATH GOES HERE"
.AllowMultiSelect = True
.Title = "Multi-select target data files:"
.ButtonName = ""
.Filters.CLEAR
.Filters.Add ".xls files", "*.xls"
.Show
End With


 For FileIdx = 1 To IndvFiles.SelectedItems.Count
Set CurrentBook = Workbooks.Open(IndvFiles.SelectedItems(FileIdx))
For Each Sheet In CurrentBook.Sheets
    Dim LRow1 As Long
    LRow1 = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim LRow2 As Long
    LRow2 = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" &     
CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Range is Columns A to Z
    Dim ImportRange As Range
    Set ImportRange = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:Z" & LRow2)
    ImportRange.Copy
    ws.Range("A" & LRow1 + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Next
CurrentBook.Close False
Next FileIdx
```

The goal is to run the macro and automatically have the 5 files consolidated into a single master sheet.

Comment: Yes that is the part that needs updating. Did you try anything yet? Effectively all you need to do is replace that section with an array of your filepaths.

Comment: `Dim filePaths`, then `filePaths = Array("path1", "path2", "path3", ...)`, then change your loop to `For FileIdx = LBound(filePaths) To UBound(filePaths)`, and then `Set CurrentBook = Workbooks.Open(filePaths(FileIdx))`